# Mysqli connection fails

Tags: php, mysql

I got

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: mysqli in /homepages/26/d186570961/htdocs/test.php on line 12

when run the `test.php` using SSH. The `test.php` is at the root folder.  I am able to run the `test.php` with my browser but not ssh.  How can I run it in ssh for crontab?  Here is my code.  Thanks for helping.

```
set_time_limit(10000);
$con = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(),   
E_USER_ERROR);}
$sqlstr = "UPDATE `oc_product` INNER JOIN `new_qty`  ON `oc_product`.`product_id`     
= `new_qty`.`product_id` SET `oc_product`.`quantity` = `new_qty`.`qty`";
$qry = $con->query($sqlstr);
```

Comment: Check if the MySQLi extension is installed and turned on in PHP-CLI. (PHP-FPM/MOD PHP/PHP-CLI usually all have their own php.ini's)

Comment: Is the CLI running a different instance of PHP?

Comment: what's your php version?